# pushing to a branch in azure dev ops (git)

Tags: reactjs, git, azure-devops

I have just started working from home and have cloned my repo from azure dev ops. 
There is a constraint set so that it can only be pushed to a branch named dev.

I have tried

```
git push -u origin dev
```

which displays this error

```
error: failed to push some refs to (then my azure dev ops url is here)
```

How would I set this up so I can push to this branch again?

This is a react project so the cli git commands are what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your workflow? (branching/merging/pr strategy)?

Usually what we do is clone the repo locally, create a feature branch (dev -> my-feature-branch), do the work and commit locally.  Then push the feature branch to the remote and then issue a PR into dev.

[image: ing]

Comment: Yep I think thats the standard for me also. Dev is already created and I have cloned the repo what is the next steps?

Comment: Actually with mine what I do is I push to just dev and the use a pr to master so its simailr to you but not exactly. I have cloned the repo now i just need to push to dev

Comment: If you cloned from the remote repo, and then you have dev checked out and you make changes to that branch and commit them locally; then all you should need to do is do a push.  You shouldn't need to specify any special parameters or anything like that since you should already be tracking the remote dev branch.

I added a screenshot to my original answer above showing how I do it against my Azure DevOps repo.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it.

```
git clone <yourrepo.git>
git checkout dev
git status
git add. 
git commit
git push origin dev
```